# Calling a method from a derived class object that returns a base class pointer

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a misunderstanding with some c++ OOP concepts, for example If I have a `base` class that returns a pointer to an object of the same class, say:

```
class base{
public:
    int baseVal;
    base* foo(){
        return new base;
    }
}
```

and a `derived` class that inherits method `foo()`:

```
class derived : public base{
public:
    int derivedVal;
    //some other members
}
```

My problem is "What will happen when I call the method `foo()` from a `derived` object? are there any way -instead of overriding- to make it return an object of `derived` not `base`?" for example:

```
int main(){
    derived obj1;
    derived * obj2P = obj1.foo();
    cout << obj2P->derivedVal << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How may I handle something like that?

Comment: Why do you not want to override? Overriding is the exact way to get that effect.

Comment: By overriding I mean writing a new method -with the same name- that returns a pointer to a `derived` object.

Comment: Well, if `foo` is not declared `virtual` in `base`, and you write another `foo` in `derived`, that would be hiding, and not technically overriding. But I still have no clue what you actually want to do.

Comment: Can I access `derived :: derivedVal` using the object returned by `base :: foo()` ?

Comment: No you cannot do that... derivedVal is data member of derived not of base.

Comment: probably an x/y question. What are you actually trying to do? That way, people can suggest solutions with a practical basis, rather than just abstractly commenting on whether something is possible, when it may not be a good idea or even what you want. Also, just in case, Google the clone pattern.

Comment: Member data should (almost) never be public...

Comment: An overridden method can return a pointer to a derived type... Not sure if it could help in your case. Search **covariance** if you want more information. In any case, it is hard to tell best solution out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a templated base class.

```
template<typename derived_t>
class base {
public:
  derived_t* foo() {
    return new derived_t;
  }
};

class derived : public base<derived> {
public:
  int derivedVal;
  //some other members
};
```

See also the CRTP pattern.

Although, it is generally bad practice to return an owning raw pointer and you should prefer to return smart pointer like `unique_ptr`:

```
template<typename derived_t>
class base {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<derived_t> foo() {
    return std::make_unique<derived_t>();
  }
};
```

Comment: Not sure if CRTP pattern is appropriate for OP.